# Mysql code for limiting the number of times some data is entered in the same msql table

Tags: mysql

i want to insert  students with the same PLE results in table `s1_east` but should not exceed 6 entries for students with the same PLE and here is my Code but only allows single entry.

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO s1_east (id,Names,PLE,Stream,School,Sex,Parent,Contact,Residence,Year)SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$Id','$Names','$PLE','$Stream','$School','$Sex','$Parent','$Contact','$Residence','$Year') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT PLE FROM s1_east WHERE PLE = '$PLE') LIMIT 1";
    $result = @mysql_query($qry);
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: am using 5.1.36 mysql version

Comment: This looks a bit like an ancient and insecure PHP API, but it can't be because that was deprecated almost a decade ago.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to care which 6 students you insert so if you are on version earlier than 8 could allocate row numbers using variables and pick those with a row number <= 6. In my example below I have limited to 2 rather than 6.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(ple int,sid int);
insert into t values
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),
(2,1),(2,2);

   select ple,sid,rn
from
(
select ple,sid, 
        if(ple<>@p,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
        @p:=ple
from t
cross join(select @rn:=0,@p:=0) r
) s
where rn <= 2;

+------+------+----+
| ple  | sid  | rn |
+------+------+----+
|    1 |    1 |  1 |
|    1 |    2 |  2 |
|    2 |    1 |  1 |
|    2 |    2 |  2 |
+------+------+----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```